# Problema al llamar elemento con findViewById

Tags: android, android-studio

Estimados, tengo una función llamada `Reproductor()`, el fin de esta es utilizar la clase `MediaPlayer`, tanto como para reproducir como para darle pause.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import java.io.IOException;


public class Reproductor extends Activity {
public String urlMediaPlayer ="url-media";
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();


ProgressBar progressBar;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    System.out.println("Reproductor, onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);
    this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fabProgressBar);
    reproduceMedia();
}

    public Reproductor() {
}

public void reproduceMedia()
{
    cargaMedia cmedia = new cargaMedia();
    cmedia.execute();
}

public class cargaMedia extends AsyncTask<Void,Integer,Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

       progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try{
           mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
           mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urlMediaPlayer);
           mediaPlayer.prepare();
           mediaPlayer.setVolume(1,1);
           mediaPlayer.start();
       }catch (IOException e)

       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

           return true;
    }

}

public void pausaMedia() throws IOException{

    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(urlMediaPlayer);
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0,0);
    mediaPlayer.pause();

}
```

}
Esta funcion es llamada desde la clase `ContainerActivity`, presionando un `FloatingActionButton`.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.IdRes;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;

import com.roughike.bottombar.BottomBar;
import com.roughike.bottombar.OnTabSelectListener;

import cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.R;
import cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.Reproductor;
import 
cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.view.fragment.DeportesFragment;
import 
cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.view.fragment.HomeFragment;
import 
cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.view.fragment.PoliticaFragment;

public class ContainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_container);

    BottomBar bottomBar = (BottomBar) findViewById(R.id.bottonbar);
    bottomBar.setDefaultTab(R.id.portada);


    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();


 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container,homeFragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
.addToBackStack(null).commit();

    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) 
     findViewById(R.id.fab);


    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           // Reproductor reproductor = new Reproductor();

           // reproductor.reproduceMedia();

            Intent intent = new Intent(ContainerActivity.this, 
    Reproductor.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
     Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
        }

    });

    bottomBar.setOnTabSelectListener(new OnTabSelectListener() {
@Override
public void onTabSelected(@IdRes int tabId) {
    switch (tabId){
        case R.id.portada:
            HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
         .replace(R.id.container,homeFragment)

         .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
       case R.id.deportes:
            DeportesFragment deportesFragment = new DeportesFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.container,deportesFragment)

         .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
         .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.politica:
            PoliticaFragment politicaFragment = new PoliticaFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
           .replace(R.id.container,politicaFragment)

          .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
           .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            break;
       }
    }
  });

}


@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
}
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
}
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

  }
}
```

Deseo que por mientras se carga el audio me muestre el `progressbar`, y una vez esté listo, desaparezca y me muestre un botón pause. Pero con el código que tengo al presionar en el `floating` `actionbutton` me envía un error de `NullPointerException`.

> PID:936
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
>   'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null
>   object  reference
>                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2090)
>                                                                                          at cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.Reproductor.
>   (Reproductor.java:21)
>                                                                                          at cl.cooperativa.readxmlfrominternetmaterial.view
>
> .ContainerActivity$1.onClick(ContainerActivity.java:42)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
>                                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
>   .run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con "android-studio"?

Answer (score 1):

Aqui esta el problema:

```
public class Reproductor extends Activity {
  //..
  ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fabProgressBar);
```

El metodo `findViewById` funciona en conjunto [`setContentView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(int)).

> setContentView asigna el contenido de la vista desde un recursod XML.

`findViewById` requiere de una vista asignada al Activity para funcionar y para asignar una vista al `Activity` se utiliza `setContentView`. Y el lugar propicio para asignar la vista con `setContentView` a un Activity es sobreescribiendo el metodo `onCreate` del `Activity`

No veo que le asignas la vista al Activity `Reproductor`.
Debes de asignarle una vista al Activity y despues de haber asignado la vista buscas el elemento:

public class Reproductor extends Activity {

```
 ProgressBar progressBar;

 public void OnCreate(Bundle saveInstance)
 { 
    setContentView(R.layout.vistaConElLoadingRing);
    this.progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.fabProgressBar);
 }
//...
```

Nota: Te recomiendo que leas sobre los [Activity y sus ciclos de vida en la documentacion oficial](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html?hl=es-419) para que tengas una idea mas solida de lo que hacen. Consiguete un refresco y palomitas porque sera una larga lectura.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero lamentablemente no logro solucionar el problema, ocurre lo mismo, veo que al presionar el Floating no entra al onCreate.

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Para que se ejecute `onCreate` tienes que inicializar la actividad con `startActivity`. `startActivity(Reproductor.class);`. Lo que pasa es que estas utilizando el `Activity` de forma incorrecta. Un `Activity` no es para iniciar una instancia de la clase y ya. Es para utilizarlo con un View y `startActivity`

Comment: Edité mi pregunta con el código nuevo, pero te comento que me abre una pantalla en blanco, que efectívamente es activity_container pero lamentablemente no me muestra las cardview cargadas anteriormente.

Comment: Te lanza algun error que no te las muestra?

Comment: Ningún error, solo me muestra la pantalla blanca

Comment: Muestra el contenido del activity para poder echarle un vistazo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus respuestas, el código de la pregunta es el que tengo actualmente, se deseas te puedo dejar la url de github.